# Why I have style in netcore razor view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I am wondering why i have this class when I have carefully look at all the style I have import into my site and I can't found it (in fact I have modify it from name

```
fp-accordion-card_accordionCardButton
```

To New Name

```
fp-accordion-card_accordionCardButton
```

Comment: Stop debugging and save the changes. Then try again.

Comment: I have done it many time.But I don't know why this style is still there? Haiza.

Comment: Actually, I have seen this myself. Try closing the project, now use explorer, browse to your project dir. Now delete the following folders: '.vs', 'bin' and 'obj'. Now open the project and recompile (that will recreate the folders).

Comment: I have tried this but it not work.

Comment: Did you use it and then go to the web to view it? Or did you go to the plug-in directory of the style to look for but did not find it? I created a project and didn’t have this style. What plug-in did you use?

Comment: Yes, I have use it, But after that I have change it's name in the css file anh also change in the razor view. No more using it. And It is still there, keeping me anoy.Haiz.a